# Creating a list that has to be accessed by the classes it uses C++

Tags: c++, allegro5

I need to create a global list that can be accessed and used by a group of classes that I have initialised, but those classes need to be included to create the list. Any ideas?

Example:

```
class Game_object
{
  public:
  ~Game_object()
  void Update();
  void Render();
  //Other stuff
};

class Explosion
{
    Stuff
};

class Player
{
      Stuff
};
```

All of these classes need to access the list below, that is in another header file, as well as my int main

```
std::list <Game_object *> Objects;
std::list <Explosion *> Explosions;
```

And so on.

The idea was that I could create an explosion instance in the destructor of the Game_object, and place it inside of the list. This was so I could have it rendering and updating inside of main

Comment: In my experience, a better solution to this problem is to make those classes *not* need access to such lists by moving the logic that needs it elsewhere.

Comment: I have to agree with molbdnilo here, messing around with forward declarations and externs will result in difficult to maintain, interdependant spaghetti code. The best approach is to redesign what it is you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `Game_object` should hold a `std::list<Explosion *>` and `Explosion` should hold a `std::list<Game_object *>`? It sounds like a job for [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

```
#include <list>

class Game_object;
class Explosion;

class Game_object
{
    std::list<Explosion *> l;
};

class Explosion
{
    std::list<Game_object *> l;
};
```

This works because your lists contain *pointers*, not actual objects.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your lists in a header file (for example, mylists.h) like this:

```
#include <list>
#include <myGameClasses.h>

class Game_object;
class Explosion;

extern std::list<Game_object*> Objects;
extern std::list<Explosion*> Explosions;
// And so for other lists
```

Using extern will create a *referencing declaration* for your lists. You should then create the *defining declarations* in a source file (for example, mylists.cpp):

```
#include "mylists.h"

std::list<Game_object*> Objects;
std::list<Explosion*> Explosions;
// And so for other lists
```

Why should you do it like this? This is to prevent multiple declarations when including your header (mylists.h). Only one declaration will then be necessary which, in this case, in the source file (mylists.cpp).

To be able to use the lists, just include the header file.

Also, in mylists.h, there is also a need to for *forward declarations* of your classes:

```
class Game_object;
class Explosion;
```

This is to avoid an undeclared identifier errors.

Comment: This was the way I was trying to do it, but to include Game_object, I needed to include the Game_object header, and it would give me an error saying that the game_object and explosion class did not exist

Comment: @Masoman3 Are you sure you added the forward declarations for your classes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's no good idea to access these lists but if you need this kind of acces you can do it by many ways, the most simple by global variables:

```
// forward declare Game_object:
class Game_object;

// Declare lists:
typedef std::list <Game_object *> ListObjects;
typedef std::list <Explosion *> ListExplosions;
ListObjects Objects;
ListExplosions Explosions;

class Game_object
{
    public:
    void Update()
    {
        // Update Objects...
        for (ListObjects::const_iterator O = Objects.begin(); O != Objects.end(); ++O)
        { ... };
        // Update Explosions...
        for (ListExplosions::const_iterator E = Explosions.begin(); E != Explosions.end(); ++E)
        { ... };
    };
    void Render()
    {
        // Render Objects...
        for (ListObjects::const_iterator O = Objects.begin(); O != Objects.end(); ++O)
        { ... };
        // Render Explosions...
        for (ListExplosions::const_iterator E = Explosions.begin(); E != Explosions.end(); ++E)
        { ... };
    };
    //Other stuff
};
```

It isn't a good idea, the global variables could be troublesome, even worse with global lists that can be accessed by some other classes and alter its contents while another class try to alter the contents at the same time; but if you're not using threads it couldn't be that troublesome.

Other approach could be to create a manager. The manager must be the owner of the list and would need the methods `Setters`, `Getters`, and `Deleters` methods. To update the contents of the list you can pass a reference to the manager to a renderer/updater and get a reference to the list from the manager:

```
class ObjectManager
{
public:
    typedef std::list <Game_object *> ListObjects;

    void AddObject(const ObjectStuff &os)
    { ... };

    const ListObjects &GetObjects()
    { return Objects; };

private:
    ListObjects Objects;
}

class ExplosionManager
{
public:
    typedef std::list <Explosion *> ListExplosions;

    void AddExplosion(const ExplosionStuff &es);
    { ... };

    const ListExplosions &GetExplosions()
    { return Explosions; };

private:
    ListExplosions Explosions;
}

void Render(const ObjectManager &om)
{
    // Ask ObjectManager for the object list
}

void Render(const ExplosionManager &em)
{
    // Ask ExplosionManager the explosion list
}
```

The above code is a naive and pretty simple approximation but is only for example purposes. The advantage of the above approach is that the list is modified only by the owner object, if the list is needed out of the manager is provided in a read-only manner and if you are using threads, is pretty simple to add the locks and unlocks in the manager methods in order to avoid the modifications while the list is used.

---

This isn't asked but I think is worth to say: Could be a good idea to avoid storing object pointers into containers and change the store type by object instances:

```
std::list <Game_object *> VS std::list <Game_object>
```

When you're using pointers you must take care of the allocation and deallocation of the objects, if the lists are global you'll need a public `Close` method to deallocate all the memory managed by the pointers stored in the lists, if the list is owned by some object, you need to do the same process into the object destructor.

But, if you're storing object instances, the list destructor deallocates all the objects stored when it's lifetime ends, the code is cleaner and easier to maintain.